# How do I sort a list when using List Rendering in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working with List Rendering in Vue2. The list renders OK, but is ordered based on the order of the data in my array. Therefore, I need to sort each item on screen by title (a-z). I can not seem to figure out how to do this when I also have a search input (filteredBlogs) in use as well. Any help welcome.

```
   const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            search: '',
             blogs: [
              { 
                title: 'Northern Towns' ,
                location: 'Leeds'
              },
              { 
                title: 'Things to do in Leeds' ,
                location: 'Yorkshire'
              },
              { 
                title: 'Visit the beach',
                location: 'Cornwall'
              }
            ]
        },
    computed: {
        filteredBlogs:function(){
            return this.blogs.filter((blog) => {
              return blog.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||  blog.location.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
              .sort((a, b) => {
                  if (a.title < b.title)
                      return -1;
                  if (a.title > b.title)
                      return 1;
                  return 0;
            });
        }
    }
    });
```

HTML is as follows;

```
<div id="app">
    <label>
        Search name: <input type="text" v-model='searchString'>
    </label> <br>
    <li v-for='item in filteredBlogs' :key='item.id' class="my-list-item">
        {{item.title}}
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you filter an original array, second you sort filtered array

```
computed: {
  filteredBlogs:function(){
    const filteredBlogs = this.blogs.filter((blog) => blog.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||  blog.location.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()))
    filteredBlogs.sort((a, b) => {
                  if (a.title < b.title)
                      return -1;
                  if (a.title > b.title)
                      return 1;
                  return 0;
            });
    return filteredBlogs
  }
}
```